# Track database schema changes in MS SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, database, database-schema

We have a database in MS SQL Server 2000.
A column in one table disappeared one day and I have no idea why it happened or when it happened.
(Please don't laugh, this is an old app and the architecture design is not as good as I thought. I'm a new support guy for the app.)

Do you know how to track changes in database schemas for MS SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 1):

After the fact you're not going to have much to go on, but start with "who has rights to do it?", and ask them all.

You could possibly narrow the "when" down by restoring the oldest backup you have, looking to see if the column is there, and working forward. If the database is in full recovery mode, and you have all the transaction logs, you could restore the database and apply logs until the column disappears, but this will still only give you a when, and not a who.

Answer (score 1):

Database tables should never be modified through the GUI because there is no record of the schema changes.

In the olden days we would have schema scripts placed in an shared folder so we could track the changes. Therefore an employee could just ask around to see who created the script. Do you have .sql files stored anywhere?

Another very simple source control idea is to have a single script of the entire database stored in TFS or Subversion and just script the database weekly. This allows you to compare scripts side by side so you can visually see changes. I think redgate have a tool that automates this in some way.

Definitely something to think about moving forward :)